# How to add new categories in Wordpress search.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm struggling to add new categories in search.php. But I failed. Actually the php file is beyond me. I need help :( I have 4 categories, location, sub-location, city and municipality. But these search codes use only titles. How can I add these categories in search.php file? Anybody can say the resolve please?

```
if( isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'noo_property' ) :
?>
<?php 

global $wp_query;

$show_map = noo_get_option('noo_property_listing_map',1);
$show_search = noo_get_option('noo_property_listing_search',1);
$disable_map = ( ! $show_map && $show_search ) ? ' disable_map="true"' : '';
$disable_search_form = ( $show_map && ! $show_search )  ? ' disable_search_form="true"' : '';
$search_layout = noo_get_option('noo_property_listing_map_layout','horizontal');
$advanced_search = ($show_search && noo_get_option('noo_property_listing_advanced_search',0)) ? ' advanced_search="true"' : '';

$title = __('Properties matching your search', 'noo');
?>
<?php get_header();

?>
<div class="container-wrap">

    <?php if(!empty($show_map) || !empty($show_search)):?>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[noo_advanced_search_property style="'.$search_layout.'"' . $disable_map . $disable_search_form . $advanced_search . ']');?>
    <?php endif;?>
    <div class="main-content container-boxed max offset">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="<?php noo_main_class(); ?>" role="main">
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <?php 
                    $args = array(
                        'query' => $wp_query,
                        'title' => $title,
                        'display_mode' => true,
                        'default_mode' => '',
                        'show_pagination' => true,
                        'ajax_pagination' => false,
                        'show_orderby' => noo_get_option('noo_property_listing_orderby', 1)
                    );
                    re_property_loop( $args ); ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php noo_get_layout( 'no-content' ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php 
                    wp_reset_query();
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
            </div> <!-- /.main -->
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div><!--/.row-->
    </div><!--/.container-boxed-->
</div><!--/.container-wrap-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>

<?php else :
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container-wrap">

    <div class="main-content container-boxed max offset">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="<?php noo_main_class(); ?> <?php noo_page_class(); ?>" role="main">
                <h1><?php _e('Results For', 'noo'); ?><span>"<?php the_search_query(); ?>"</span></h1>

                <div id="search-results">

                    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                            <?php if( get_post_type($post->ID) == 'post' ){ ?>
                                <article class="result">
                                    <div class="content-featured">
                                        <?php noo_featured_content( $post->ID ); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <small><?php echo __('Blog Post', 'noo'); ?></small></h2>
                                    <?php if(get_the_excerpt()) the_excerpt(); ?>
                                    <hr/>
                                </article><!--/search-result--> 
                            <?php }

                            else if( get_post_type($post->ID) == 'page' ){ ?>
                                <article class="result">
                                    <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <small><?php echo __('Page', 'noo'); ?></small></h2>    

                                    <?php if(get_the_excerpt()) the_excerpt(); ?>
                                    <hr/>
                                </article><!--/search-result--> 
                            <?php }

                            else if( get_post_type($post->ID) == 'product' ){ ?>
                                <article class="result">
                                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) { 
                                        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'. get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'full', array('title' => '')).'</a>'; 
                                    } ?>
                                    <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <small><?php echo __('Product', 'noo'); ?></small></h2> 
                                    <?php if(get_the_excerpt()) the_excerpt(); ?>
                                    <hr/>
                                </article><!--/search-result--> 
                            <?php } else if( get_post_type($post->ID) == 'noo_property' ){ ?>
                                <article class="result">
                                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) { 
                                        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'. get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'property-image', array('title' => '')).'</a>'; 
                                    } ?>
                                    <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <small><?php echo __('Property', 'noo'); ?></small></h2>    
                                    <?php if(get_the_excerpt()) the_excerpt(); ?>
                                    <hr/>
                                </article><!--/search-result--> 
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <article class="result">
                                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) { 
                                        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'full', array('title' => '')).'</a>'; 
                                    } ?>
                                    <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                                    <?php if(get_the_excerpt()) the_excerpt(); ?>
                                    <hr/>
                                </article><!--/search-result--> 
                            <?php } ?>

                    <?php endwhile; 

                    else: echo "<p>" . __('No results found', 'noo') . "</p>"; endif;?>

                </div><!--/search-results-->

                <?php noo_pagination(); ?>
            </div> <!-- /.main -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div><!--/.row-->
    </div><!--/.container-boxed-->
</div><!--/.container-wrap-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I looking wrong php file? Or true